# Create mask based on multiple conditions that compare datetime64 timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with 7 columns of timestamps in datetime64 format. The first two columns are 'Time_in' and 'Time_out', which signify the beginning and end of day. The next two columns are 'Time_in1' and 'Time_out1'. The final two are 'Time_in2' and 'Time_out2'. These last sets of times are between 'Time_in' and 'Time_out'. The final column is 'time' against which all other columns are compared. An example of one from from this dataframe could be (the format also has year-month-day but I am simplifying by just showing the times):

Time_in= 9am

Time_out = 5pm

Time_in1 = 11am

Time_out1 = 12pm

Time_in2 = 3pm

Time_out2 = 4pm

I would like to create a mask column that is True if:

time>=Time_in and time<=Time_out

and

time<=Time_in1 and time>=Time_out1

and

time<=Time_in2 and time>=Time_out2

The first part works by the following snippet:

```
df['wearing_time'] = ((df['time']>=flmerge.Time_in) & (df['time']<=df.Time_out))
```

I believe this works because there are no blank values.

However, I have tried the following with no success:

```
df['wearing_time'] = ((df['time']>=flmerge.Time_in) & (df['time']<=df.Time_out)) and ((df['time']>=df.Time_out1) and (df['time']<=df.Time_in1)) and ((df['time']>=df.Time_out2) & (df['time']<=df.Time_in2))
```

as well as:

```
df['wearing_time'] = ((df['time']>=dfe.Time_in) & (df['time']<=df.Time_in1) & (df['time']>=df.Time_out1) & (df['time']<=df.Time_in2) & (flmerge['time']>=df.Time_out2) & (df['time']<=df.Time_out))
```

which give the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'
```

I believe the problem is that there are not always values for Time_in1/Time_in2 or Time_out1/Time_out2.  I attempted to do the above in a loop (row by row) so that I could test for the presence or absence of a value, and run the boolean query if the value is present. But it is extremely inefficient and will probably take days to do this(!).

If anyone has any beautifully efficient suggestions, I would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example, you want to filter if at a given time `time` something had a kind of break? (between `11am` and `12am`, or between `3pm` and `4pm`).

So, another logic would be:

```
# working hours:
(Time_in <= @time) and (Time_out >= @time)
# not in a break:
and not (((Time_in1 <= @time) and (Time_out1 >= @time)) or
((Time_in2 <= @time) and (Time_out2 >= @time)))
```

If you now assume that something/somebody who has no `Time_in1/Time_out1` did not have a break, you can replace the empty strings (or `NaNs`) with a datetime outside your query, for example:

```
import datetime
df.replace(np.NaN, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0), inplace=True)

time = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 15, 0)

times = df2.query("(Time_in <= @time) and (Time_out >= @time)
      and not (((Time_in1 <= @time) and (Time_out1 >= @time)) or
      ((Time_in2 <= @time) and (Time_out2 >= @time)))")
```

You can use any type of comparisons here (I just like the `query` method), but the idea to solve your problem it to write your logic in a way that the missing entries can be replaced with `datetimes` from the past, eleminating the

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'
```

error.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your reply Chris.  I was not aware of the pandas query method. It has slightly unfamiliar syntax to me; I have not used the '@' symbol before - is this as simple as coding '@column_name' (or am I way off base)?  Also, can you tell me if query performs operations on the dataframe by row, across columns?  Thanks, I am just looking some documentation now!

Comment: In case you've not found the page yet: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html . A query string could be explained like this: `.query("column_name_of_dataframe == 'somestring'")`. If you want to use a variable instead of the string (or a numeric value), then you can use the `@`. This means the following word is a variable (and the value will be substituted).

Comment: Thanks @chris-sc. I have also been looking at examples on this page: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax). However I am getting an error when I try to create a new column in the same dataframe based on the three columns of interest, starting with something simple: 
    df['boolean']=df.query("(Time_in<=timestamp) and (Time_out>=timestamp)")
and I get the error:
    *** ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 30, placement implies 1
When I add @ symbols the variables are no longer recognized.